# How to check if the url contains JSON file

Tags: python, json, api, flask, python-requests

I'm working with **League of Legends API**, and I'm trying to get Ranked Datas from **JSON** file. But, if the player is not **Level 30**, he doesn't have his file.
So here

```
def getRankedData(region, ID, APIkey):
    URL = "https://" + region + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v2.5/league/by-summoner/" + ID + "/entry?api_key=" + APIkey
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()
```

It won't get **JSON** file, because it doesn't exist. How do i can do, that if the **URL** doesn't exist and doesn't have the JSON file, it returns the string.

Here, I'm returning the datas to **HTML** page. But this isn't work too.

```
 region = request.form['region']
 summonerName = request.form['summonerName']
 APIkey = "45afde27-b628-473f-9a94-feec8eb86094"
 types = request.form['types']
 responseJSON = getData(region, summonerName, APIkey)
 ID = responseJSON[summonerName]['id']
 ID = str(ID)
 responseJSON2 = getRankedData(region, ID, APIkey)
 if not responseJSON2:
     divisionName = "Unranked"
 else: 
     divisionName = responseJSON2[ID][0]['name']
 responseJSON3 = getChallengerPlayers(region, str(types), APIkey)
 challengerPlayers = responseJSON3['entries'][0]['wins']
 #print challengerPlayers

 return render_template('form_action.html', ID = ID, divisionName = divisionName, challengerPlayers = challengerPlayers)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in      handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in     full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in  handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in     full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in  dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Hanisek\Documents\Visual Studio     2015\Projects\FlaskWebProject2\FlaskWebProject2\FlaskWebProject2\views.py", line 53, in hello
responseJSON2 = getRankedData(region, ID, APIkey)
File "C:\Users\Hanisek\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FlaskWebProject2\FlaskWebProject2\FlaskWebProject2\views.py", line 21, in getRankedData
Open an interactive python shell in this framereturn response.json()
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\models.py", line 805, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of the response?

Comment: @albert What do you mean?

Comment: The error is raised because the response cannot be decoded as a json object. So having a look at the response might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know a ton about LOL but is there a reason that you cant have your program use and if/then statement to check the level of the player and then only check for the json file if the player is a high enough level to have one?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Better then 100 rows of coding.

Comment: no problem, often the simplest answer is the correct one ~ occams razor

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to check what the api url is returning by running it in your browser. I'm guessing that it's returning a 404 error because the information doesn't exist.

In that case, I recommend checking to see if there is a 404 error before proceeding with the JSON parsing.

Request has a function called [status_code](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) that will return the 404 error if there is one.
Example code:

```
r = request.get("API STRING")
if r.status_code != 404:
    r.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking if the URL exists, JSON is proper format or if the page throws 40X status codes

```
try:
    r = requests.get("URL")
    assert r.status_code < 400
    return r.json()
except (ValueError, ConnectionError, AssertionError):
    return ''
```